# Get coordinates on click without using QgsMapToolEmitPoint

Tags: pyqgis, labeling, coordinates, tools

I have a code that reacts to a mouse click. I click on the label of an object and get the ID of this object. Everything works perfectly. But I need to do all the same when some other tool is active ("Move a Label..." tool). Or at worst, so that this code is always executed regardless of the selected tool. Is there a way to achieve this?

```
def canvasPressEvent(event):
    x = event.pos().x()
    y = event.pos().y()
    point = canvas.getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
    labels = iface.mapCanvas().labelingResults().labelsAtPosition(QgsPointXY(point))    
    if labels:
        print (labels[0].featureId)
from qgis.gui import QgsMapToolEmitPoint
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
pointTool = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(canvas)
pointTool.canvasPressEvent = canvasPressEvent
canvas.setMapTool(pointTool)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to get the coordinates regardless of the selected tool is using an [Event Filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) to intercept the mouse events of the `QgsMapCanvas` object.

Within the event filter function there is a check for the correct event type, in this case `QEvent.MouseButtonPress`, and then you can access coordinates exactly the same as in your code example.

```py
class MouseClickFilter(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MouseClickFilter, self).__init__(parent)
    
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress: 
            x = event.pos().x()
            y = event.pos().y()
            point = iface.mapCanvas().getCoordinateTransform().toMapCoordinates(x, y)
            print(point)
            
        return False
            

click_filter = MouseClickFilter()
iface.mapCanvas().viewport().installEventFilter(click_filter)
```

Note that if you want to filter mouse events, you need to install the event filter on the canvas' viewport. For other events (e.g. key press) `iface.mapCanvas().installEventFilter(filter)` is sufficient.

Comment: Wow! This is magic, works great! Thanks a lot!