# Run function from QGIS plugin with canvasReleaseEvent

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

In this topic https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430301/192997 it is explained how to run a basic function from a canvas event :

> *Code edited by changing `QgsMapTool` by `QgsMapToolPan`*:

```
def test(event):
    print('canvas release')

tool = QgsMapToolPan(iface.mapCanvas())
tool.canvasReleaseEvent = test
iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

I try to do the same to run a function from a plugin (made with PluginBuilder) with `canvasReleaseEvent`:

```
class MyPlugin:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):
        """Constructor."""

        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg = MyPluginDialog()

        #code......


    def tr(self, message):
        
        #code......

    def add_action(
        self,
        icon_path,
        text,
        callback,
        enabled_flag=True,
        add_to_menu=True,
        add_to_toolbar=True,
        status_tip=None,
        whats_this=None,
        parent=None):
        
        #code......

    def initGui(self):

        #code......


    def unload(self):

        #code......


    def run(self):
    
    if self.first_start == True:
        self.first_start = False

    # show the dialog
    self.dlg.show()
    # Run the dialog event loop
    result = self.dlg.exec_()
    # See if OK was pressed
    if result:
        # Do something useful here - delete the line containing pass and
        # substitute with your code.
        pass

    tool = QgsMapToolPan(self.iface.mapCanvas())
    tool.canvasReleaseEvent = lambda event self.function_from_plugin(event)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)


    def function_from_plugin(self, event):
        if self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value() == 1:
        ### rest of the code
```

but I get this error : `AttributeError: 'QgsMapMouseEvent' object has no attribute 'dlg'`

I looked other topics but I can't manage to understand everything:

[How to link my QGIS plugin main class to mouse events from a custom Tool?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133070/how-to-link-my-qgis-plugin-main-class-to-mouse-events-from-a-custom-tool)

https://gis-ops.com/qgis-3-plugin-tutorial-pyqt-signal-slot-explained/

Comment: Since you need to use `iface` in the script, `__init__`  method have to include `self.iface = iface`

Answer (score 6):

In your plugin script, you define `tool` in the main scope of the class. It means that `tool` runs every time QGIS loads the plugin. That means the plugin button will have no function.

You must define  `tool` in `run` method to bind the tool to the button in the plugin toolbar. Because the plugin button runs `run` method.

You can use the following structure:

```
...

def function_from_plugin(self, event):
    if self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value() == 1:
        ### rest of the code
    
def run(self):
    tool = QgsMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
    tool.canvasReleaseEvent = lambda event: self.function_from_plugin(event)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

If your plugin is not very complex, I recommend using [Minimal QGIS Plugin](https://github.com/wonder-sk/qgis-minimal-plugin), instead of Plugin Builder, as follows. In this case, you just need `__init__.py` and `metadata.txt`.

```
from qgis.gui import QgsMapTool
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction

def classFactory(iface):
    return MinimalPlugin(iface)


class MinimalPlugin:
    def __init__(self, iface):
        self.iface = iface

    def initGui(self):
        self.action = QAction('Go!', self.iface.mainWindow())
        self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
        self.iface.addToolBarIcon(self.action)

    def unload(self):
        self.iface.removeToolBarIcon(self.action)
        del self.action

    def function_from_plugin(self, event):
        print("canvas released")
        
    def run(self):
        tool = QgsMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        tool.canvasReleaseEvent = lambda event: self.function_from_plugin(event)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question Kadir. I think I have not well built my plugin... Is it compulsory to write the plugin functions in def run(self) ? 
I did another way (see my edit)

Comment: ```def function_from_plugin(self, event):
    if self.dlg.horizontalSlider.value() == 1:
        ### rest of the code
    
def run(self):
    tool = QgsMapTool(self.iface.mapCanvas())
    tool.canvasReleaseEvent = lambda event: self.function_from_plugin(event)
    self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool(tool)```

Unfortunately nothings occurs when I insert this lines in my plugin script :(

Comment: Please add the whole structure of your last script to the question body so that we can check what is wrong.  Comment area is not appropriate for codes as you see.

Comment: Understood Kadir, I edited the code in the topic

Comment: Sorry my mistake, your solution is working. It is just not working with QgsMapToolPan, do you know why ?